# Authentification with just a password

Tags: firebase, vue.js, authentication

I currently built a small WebApp for personal use. I want to push it online but not everyone should have access to it. I want to send the password to people which I will allow to access the site but I only want one password which can everyone use. I build the App with just Nuxt.js and firestore because I'm not familiar with backend technology.

I'm aware of the firebase authentication, but it only supports authentication with e-mail address.

Does someone know a simple Method how I can do this? Security is in this case not very import, I just want that not everyone can go on the site yet.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you're aware of firebase authentication, create a single account with email and password. For now, on login screen you can pass `email` hardcoded in `input[type='hidden']` field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic authentication for that. Not the most secure way of securing a site since the credentials are sent over with each request but If your site is under https you should be fine.